# Show all tabs with worksheet names (use multiple rows, or alternative, if needed)

Tags: excel, tabs, worksheet

I have a workbook with many worksheets. I would like to see the tabs for all available worksheets at once, which will need more than one row of tabs at the bottom. From what I searched, this is not possible.

The closest I got is right clicking on the arrows for navigating the sheets (at the bottom left), and then "More Sheets..."

Is there anything that gives more visibility at once?

Comment: Is this related to programming anyhow?

Comment: It is. Just check the answer by @GarysStudent. I could not ascertain that the solution is provided by programming, but it may be.

Comment: @Kamiccolo : Do you think it is not? It is always good to have another point of view.

Comment: @pnuts - I wouldn't call it "wrong". But it does not do what I mean to get: To see in the main Excel window, without requiring any key pressing or mouse action, the tabs for all existing sheets (e.g., in a multirow).

Comment: @pnuts - There is no multirow for tabs. I did not mean to request it, but to ask about possible alternatives/replacements (e.g., a good answer below). In one workbook I have 46, and I expect to have more.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Table of Contents worksheet.  Each cell in this sheet would display a tab name and contain a hyperlink to that tab.

You can do this manually or with a macro

Comment: I thought about this option, but this will require navigating to the index sheet first. Moreover, clicking on a hyperlink may lead to a predefined cell in the target sheet, instead of preserving the currently active cell (or object) in the sheet. One would have to define a `Sub` for the `Event` of activating the index sheet, so it records at that point the active cell/object in each sheet and sets all hyperlinks (somewhat) appropriately.

Comment: All you comments are correct.  Another approach would be to use **Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick** event and simply Activate or Select the worksheet named in the cell

Comment: That at least gets rid of losing the AcitveCell.

Comment: `RangeSelection` may be useful here. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24966051/2707864).

Comment: Gary's Student: I think the approach with `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` is well worth posting as another solution.