# VBA: Get selected Range in a Worksheet where the Selection is a Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet, with a Chart in it. If I select a range of cells, and then I select the Chart, then in the immediate window of the VBE

```
? TypeName(Selection)
ChartArea
```

So I cannot use `Selection` to get the selected `Range`, even if it is there (pressing Esc returns to the selected range of cells).

How can I retrieve that `Range` in VBA?

PS: I suspect the same Q&A applies to other `Shape`s.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  If you select a range of cells, the click the chart, you want `Selection` to return the cells you previously selected even though the range is no longer selected?

Comment: I believe once you select the chart, you're no longer "in" the worksheet you're using. Maybe try using the "Parent.Selection"? I don't know if that even works, but maybe you get my logic...

Comment: @psubsee2003 - No, I do not want `Selection` to return the cells that I previously selected, because it will simply not do that. But I do want to retrieve that range (by whatever method).

Comment: @BernardSaucier - I think it does not work.

Comment: @sancho.s I think you may have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Rather than worrying about `Selection`, your issue is probably related to why you need the selected range even when clicking a chart.  Maybe explaining will help.  I don't think there is a solution to your question as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `RangeSelection` property of the `Window` object (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194102%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).

Comment: My response refers to the RangeSelection property - not Selection