# Detect the type of Selection in a Worksheet just deactivated

Tags: excel, selection, vba

I want a method to inquire, after changing the `ActiveSheet`, without additional Activating/Deactivating:

1. The type of `Selection` in the previous active sheet (of most importance, if it was a `ChartObject` or `Range`).
2. If it is a `Range`, get the address.

Is this possible ...?

PS: answers to this one will help me getting to the answer of [Detect the type of Selection in a Worksheet just deactivated, in any open Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973905/detect-the-type-of-selection-in-a-worksheet-just-deactivated-in-any-open-workbo). But they are not the same.

Comment: You would need to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` Event in every sheet within the book. But potentially you could use a public variable and the `TypeOf()` method to achieve this.

Comment: @SO - `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is not triggered when changing the `Selection` from a `Range` to a `Chart` ( actually, `ChartArea` with a mouse click), or viceversa if re-selecting the last previously selected `Range`. I guess this directly implies that the event is not useful for point 1.

Comment: Yes, which is why I didn't include it,  they are separate events.

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate events to capture the selection, plus a global variable to store the prior object type and name/location.

1. `Worksheet_SelectionChange` for a range
2. A `Chart_Select` event for the chartobject

For (2) in [Excel 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192964%28v=office.15%29.aspx) there is such an event but for earlier versions we will need a class module

This is accomplished using [Jon Peltier's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7441360/641067) as a base

There are three code sections below, add them to your workbook with the names and locations as indicated. Then run `Set_All_Charts` to initialise the charts in the first sheet for the chart class module

*Class Module called clsEventChart*

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents evtchart As Chart

Private Sub EvtChart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
MsgBox "Changed from : " & TypeName(X) & " " & StrPos & " to" & vbNewLine & "Chart: " & evtchart.Name
StrPos = evtchart.Name
Set X = evtchart
End Sub
```

*normal module*

```
Option Explicit

Public StrPos As String
Public X As Object
Dim clsEventCharts() As New clsEventChart

Sub Set_All_Charts()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(1)
With ws
   If .ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim clsEventCharts(1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count)
        Dim chtObj As ChartObject
        Dim chtnum As Integer

        chtnum = 1
        For Each chtObj In ws.ChartObjects
            ' Debug.Print chtObj.Name, chtObj.Parent.Name
            Set clsEventCharts(chtnum).evtchart = chtObj.Chart
            chtnum = chtnum + 1
        Next ' chtObj
   End If
End With
End Sub
```

*Sheet Event*

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox "Changed from " & TypeName(X) & ": " & StrPos & " to: " & vbNewLine & "Range: " & Target.Address
Set X = Selection
StrPos = Target.Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for part 2 of your question.

Declare oldTarget outside of the SelectionChange event so you can utilize it from other events, such as a change event.

**To place in your worksheet code:**

```
Dim oldTarget As Variant

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox ("Address changed from : " & oldTarget & vbNewLine & _
            "                   to: " & Target.Address)
    oldTarget = Target.Address

End Sub
```

**Note:** 
The first selection you make will not have an oldTarget.  After that, it will print a Message displaying the old address and new address.

Comment: I know this isn't a complete answer.  Since the question contains two questions, I'm providing this answer to provide what assistance I can. It does answer part 2 of the Question.