# How to create hyperlinks with VBA to the same open workbook

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

**The setup**

- I have an Excel workbook stored on my hard drive.
- The structure is such that on the first sheet I have a list of the names of the other sheets in the same workbook (...which can be created or deleted).
- All the names on the list, on the first sheet, are supposed to be hyperlinks to the corresponding sheet in the workbook. So, by clicking the name on the first sheet you jump to the corresponding sheet.
- When a new sheet is created a macro creates also the new name on the list on the first sheet and makes a hypelink of it. This works.
  ...BUT...
  The links point to the stored version of the file, not to the open workbook! Clicking the links opens the stored file and not the one which is under work.

**QUESTION: How to create a hyperlink that always points to the same open workbook and not to the stored copy of it?**

Comment: What's the macro code?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931104/excel-show-all-tabs-with-worksheet-names-use-multiple-rows-or-alternative-if

Comment: What do you mean by "opens the stored file"? Does clicking on the hyperlink ask you to open the stored version and discard changes? Does it happen only with the last newly created sheet? You may try saving the file as part of the automated macro (just as a workaround).

Comment: Clicking the link doesn't take me to the target sheet but opens a dialog asking if I want to open the file: the stored version of the same file which is open.

Can there be something in the Excel settings? Even a simple function on an empty workbook/worksheet: 

=HYPERLINK("Sheet2!A1";"Jump to Sheet 2")

seems to work so that it opens a dialog to open the stored version of the file from the hard drive.

Comment: Please: 1) answer the questions posted, 2) post the exact message you get. You have to help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Sheet3!", TextToDisplay:="Link to sheet #3"
```

Address is the URL and SubAddress is a localtion of the page (or a sheet or a range in excel workbooks).

Comment: Actually, my hyperlink setup looks like this: Worksheets("Summary").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Cell.Row, 5), Address:="", SubAddress:= _ "'" & sSheetName & "'!B5", TextToDisplay:=sSheetName So, the address is already "". sSheetname is a string which contains only the sheet name as a string, without any reference to anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating the hyperlink as a formula (via VBA, as you need).
I am using the parameters you posted, this may need a little adjustment.

```
Dim rngsrc as Range, rngtrgs as String
Set rngsrc = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Cell.Row, 5)
Set rngtrg = "'" & sSheetName & "'!B5"
rngsrc.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(" & rngtrgs & "," & sSheetName & ")"
```

See

[Official documentation](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-select-edit-or-delete-a-hyperlink-472fce40-c5f0-427e-90d4-12c0366bc06f#__toc289683024)

[Example 1](http://www.contextures.com/excelhyperlinkfunction.html#formula)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813626/2707864)

This (hopefully) answers your question. As a separate note, it still remains to be clarified why you see the behavior you see.

Comment: I tried this on a fresh blank workbook and still the same.
Can there be something in the Excel settings? Even a simple function on an empty workbook/worksheet: =HYPERLINK("Sheet2!A1";"Jump to Sheet 2") seems to work so that it opens a dialog to open the stored version of the file from the hard drive. Even removing the sheet-jump doesn't work: Function =HYPERLINK("A1";"Damn") doesn't take me to A1 on the same sheet but opens the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem comes from the following fact: My file is in a SharePoint folder. If I open it just for reading, the hyperlinks work fine. If I open the file for editing, a copy of the SharePoint file is placed on my hard disk, on a specified location. So, the path to the file is not the same as it would be if I open it read-only. Should I use *hyperlink.**follow*** to solve this?

So, this all comes down to the question: In VBA/Excel, *can I create a hyperlink which always points to a location in the same opened file so that the hyperlink ignores the storage path of the corresponding file?* Using empty string (or BLANK) doesn't help as the *address* parameter in *hypelinks.add* as Excel seems to automatically fill in the whole storage path.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Office 2013 and "PADAM": The problem vanished! It seems that there was a bug in Excel/VBA in this in the 2007 version.